# Slicing array in python

Tags: python, numpy

I have arrays of these shapes:

```
q.shape #(28,40,100)
g.shape #(27,40,100)
for x in range (0,100):
    for y in range (0,40):
        qg = np.interp(100,g[:,y,x],q[:,y,x]) #how?
        print qg
```

Of course it can't be interpolated because g and q don't have equal shapes. How should the script be in "#how?" section, so that q remove element [0] and only reads [1] to [27]?

Comment: Put a 1 before the colon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> only reads [1] to [27]

I believe like so

```
q[1:,y,x]
```

By the way, interpolation 4000 times might be really slow... You sure you are doing the right thing?

Comment: Haha, I'm not sure about that. As long as it results plots that I need, though. Thanks anyway